# Website is not secure. Can it be fixed without https?

Tags: google-chrome, security

I have made a website for a small local company and on that website, there's a log-in-page so the staff can edit the content. The problem is that Google Chrome says the log-in-page isn't secure. I have tried searching for solutions, but everybody just says that I just make the website https. Are there other ways to do it? The company doesn't have the budget to pay for https.

Comment: That's what the "the page is not secure" means: it's not served over https. JFYI, "https" stands for "http secure". Look into Let's Encrypt, they have free certificates. There's no reason not to do https today!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So you can't tell Chrome that there's no personal information to log in?

Comment: There is no way to "disable" this security function, it would be illegal to do that. You would hide that your sight is unsafe. You could probably do it with certificates which would have to be installed on every pc whos accessing the site.

Comment: @KasperChristoffersen: PII (personally identifiable information) has nothing to do with sites being not secure. Even if your logins/passwords can't be used to identify an individual, your login form still can be intercepted by anyone on your network (or by any intermediate node between your browser and the server). That's what "not secure" means.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these guys. => https://letsencrypt.org/

> Let’s Encrypt is a free, automated, and open certificate authority (CA), run for the public’s benefit. It is a service provided by the Internet Security Research Group (ISRG).
>
> We give people the digital certificates they need in order to enable HTTPS (SSL/TLS) for websites, for free, in the most user-friendly way we can. We do this because we want to create a more secure and privacy-respecting Web.

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled SSL on Your webserver. If you use Apache check this

```
sudo a2dismod ssl
service apache2 restart
```